# celary.py and wsgi.py: os.environ.get("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE")='proj.settings'

Tags: django, celery

**Django 1.11**

**Celery 4.0.2**

Let's read Celery's tutorial:
http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html#index-0

It says that we should place this line in celery.py:

```
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'proj.settings')
```

Nnamely the documentation says:

> You don’t need this line, but it saves you from always passing in the
>   settings module to the celery program.

I just commented this line out in my IDE. And put a breakpoint after it.

And in the debugger I checked:

```
os.environ.get("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE")='proj.settings'
```

Well, the key-value pair is already in the os.environ.

By the way, the same string is in wsgi.py:

```
os.environ.get("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE")='proj.settings'
```

It is placed there by django-admin utility when startproject was executed.

So, this doubling the same string is definitely violation of DRY principle.

By the way, settings may be stored not in proj.settings. But in settings.local and settings.production (as Two Scoops of Django recommends).

So, these two strings: in celery.py and wsgi.py are very suspicious.

Could you comment:
1. What do we need them if the value is already mapped to the key in os.environ?
2. How not to violate the DRY principle here especially if we use settings.local and settings.production)?
3. So, what does the Celery's documentation mean by "always passing in the settings module to the celery program"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1. What do we need them if the value is already mapped to the key in os.environ?

If its already set in the `settings.py` you dont need to worry about it for celery again, it's just a practise to remind you that.

> 2. How not to violate the DRY principle here especially if we use settings.local and settings.production)?

The common practise if you have `settings.local` and `settings.prod` is to include the common settings in `settings.base` or `settings.common`. So all the common settings like `BASE_DIR` etc, will go in there.

> 3. So, what does the Celery's documentation mean by "always passing in the settings module to the celery program"?

You should tell celery either to get settings from  `os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'proj.settings')` or `app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')`.

If you do the one, you can ignore the other, that's what it meant.

Comment: rrmerugu, thank you very much. I have to digest it. give me some time, please.